# Custom round function in Python

Tags: python, integer, rounding

How can I set a custom round function in Python? I want to round an integer with a step of 256, by only increasing it.

**Example** : 400 turns into 512, 1026 turns into 1280...

Any suggestions about how I could proceed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like

```
def round256(a):
    return int(a / 256) if a % 256 == 0  else (a - a % 256) + 256
```

Comment: Oh you're right, I should have thought about using modulo! Thank you.

Comment: I guess you want `a // 256 * 256` instead of `int(a / 256)`? Even simpler, and works in all cases, is `return a + (-a) % 256`.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want the `math.ceil` function scaled to an arbitrary number:

```
>>> from math import ceil
>>> def round_step(n, step):
...     return ceil(n / step) * step
...
>>> round_step(400, 256)
512
>>> round_step(1026, 256)
1280
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution would be:

```py
roundTo256 = lambda x: x + (256 - x%256)%256
```

First it calculates the distance to the next multiple of 256 (`256 - (x % 256)`), then it does `%256` on that. This is because it would be wrong for a multiple of 256, e.g. 1024 -> 256, so the value is anywhere from 1 to 256. From 1 to 255, `%256` has no effect, but `256 % 256` = 0, so it results in 0. Then it just adds the result to the original number

Comment: The extra `%` operation is unnecessary if you spell this as `lambda x: x + (-x) % 256`.